# Fixing 3 rd party classloading issue in maven/eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

My project depends on 3rd party library[ eg: json-logger) and i have included that in my project as a dependency in pom.xml.
(I have installed this library locally using maven install file command due to repository issue)

When I build my project it builds fine. But when i try to deploy that (that is, deploying the project binary after the successful build in a java based server), server throws( Mule server, java based server) error,saying class not found exception.
If I remove this library deployment is success.

But same project works ( i mean deployment )for other staff  with this same library. I have added this library in classpath too at my Anypoint studio( underneath Eclipse IDE )

What might be the cause for this?
I have done cleaning rebuilding, fresh checkout all things but same issue appears. Can anybody knows why this occurs only in my environment?
This is the libraries git location [1]

[1]https://github.com/mulesoft-consulting/json-logger/tree/mule4-v1.0.2

I get following exception[2]

[2]

```
]java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
```

**EDIT**
I have reported this issue in Mule community + json logger library too. But no response from them other than clean/rebuild etc..
Here is the link I reported in stackoverflow already.

[Mule application in anypoint studio throws Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033243/mule-application-in-anypoint-studio-throws-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexc/60068499?noredirect=1#comment106251454_60068499)

Comment: I'm not going to provide an answer at this point, because you haven't provided enough information, but perhaps we can drill down.  You haven't said anything about what "deploy that" means. There is infinite potential complexity there, and you haven't provided any details. The answer is most certainly in those details.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Thanks David..I have edited my question..Is it enough? I have provided another  SO question i have raised already..Which contain more information ( I raised it as Mule server issue, but looks no, that is why I raise it as maven/eclipse issue here)?

Comment: Mule obviously has some unusual runtime requirements.  I know nothing about that.